# Google Charts on Shiny Server not work

Tags: shiny-server, googlevis

I downloaded an example from website, which is about how to use googleVis on shiny.

It works well when running locally, however, when I deploy it on shiny server, it doesn't work any more.

Shiny server is running on Red Hat Linux, and I have deployed some other programs on server, and they all works, except this one.

server.R

```
library(googleVis)
library(shiny)
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
    datasetInput <- reactive({

})

Bubble <- gvisBubbleChart(Fruits, idvar="Fruit", 
                        xvar="Sales", yvar="Expenses",
                        colorvar="Year", sizevar="Profit",
                        options=list(
                          hAxis='{minValue:75, maxValue:125}'))
 plot(Bubble)

})
```

ui.R

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
headerPanel("Example 1: scatter chart"),
sidebarPanel(

),
mainPanel(
    htmlOutput("view")
  )
))
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's console (https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console)? Which browser and OS are you using, or does it happen on multiple browsers and OSs? Shiny Server Open Source or Pro? Which version of RedHat? Any relevant errors in `/var/log/shiny-server.log`? What does "doesn't work" mean? App disconnects? Empty spot?

Comment: It seems there is some packages not installed correctly, today I installed a package 'jsonLite', now the demo can be displayed correctly.